# How to convert a *.tab file into a dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, nltk

I'm trying to convert a *.tab file to a dictionary. There are 16 columns and 154 rows in the file, including the title. The title row and columns from 4 to 13 should be ignored. And the key for the dictionary is a tuple of strings like ('tiger, cat')

I tried an already existing solution with the code but it's showing output that is not what I expected. Here's the first few lines of the .tab file

```
Word 1  Word 2  Human (mean)    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  
love    sex 6.77    9   6   8   8   7   8   8   4   7   2   6   7   8   
tiger   cat 7.35    9   7   8   7   8   9   8.5 5   6   9   7   5   7   
tiger   tiger   10.00   10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  
book    paper   7.46    8   8   7   7   8   9   7   6   7   8   9   4   9   
computer    keyboard    7.62    8   7   9   9   8   8   7   7   6   8   10  3   9   
computer    internet    7.58    8   6   9   8   8   8   7.5 7   7   7   9   5   9   
plane   car 5.77    6   6   7   5   3   6   7   6   6   6   7   3   7   
train   car 6.31    7   7.5 7.5 5   3   6   7   6   6   6   9   4   8   
telephone   communication   7.50    7   6.5 8   8   6   8   8   7   5   9   9   8   8
```

This is the code I used:

```
import csv

with open('set1.tab') as set1:
    # skip the first line
    next(set1)
    list_of_dicts = list(csv.DictReader(set1, dialect='excel-tab'))
```

Expected result should be: {('tiger', 'cat') : 7.35, ....}

But here's my actual result:

```
[OrderedDict([('love', 'tiger'),
              ('sex', 'cat'),
              ('6.77', '7.35'),
              ('9', '9'),
              ('6', '7'),
              ('8', '7'),
              ('7', '5'),
              ('4', '5'),
              ('2', '9'),
              ('', '')]),
```

Comment: What is a "*.tab" file?

Comment: @UweKeim I think it is a tsv file..?

Comment: * is a file name and .tab is the extension. Apologies if I wasn't clear

Comment: @ArupRakshit Oh. I'm sorry I didn't know that. I'm kind of new to Python

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
import csv

with open('set1.tab') as set1:
    # skip the first line
    next(set1)
    rows = csv.reader(set1, dialect='excel-tab')
    dict_data = {(fields[0], fields[1]): fields[2:] for fields in rows if len(fields) >= 2}
    print(dict_data)
```